# nativebase autocomplete Unable to find

Tags: react-native, native-base

I'm new to React Native & I'm using NativeBase to build my demo app. I'm not able to create AutoComplete Searchbox using nativebase. Can anyone help me to give any example? My Requirement:
1. Rounded Search Box
2. Once Click it should show cancel button
3. After typing 2 letter it should give provide option to user for select
4. Select the option.

I searched in Google. However unable to find anything which suffice my requirement. Can anyone please help.

Comment: auto-complete feature is not related to UI, so NativeBase shouldn't be doing anything here

Comment: the issue is that Native Base uses its own Input field, and the generic TextInput that your typical autocomplete library is built off isn't compatible with some of Native Base's UI elements, such as Label fields in Forms.

Answer (score 1):

for your exact requirement you can write your own code. I tried to write autocomplete functionality. You can check in [Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@arpitg/autocomplete).

This is basic code for react-native autocomplete functionality.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

export default class AutoCompleteBasics extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      text: '',
      textInputFocus: false,
      arrayList: ['Apple', 'Mango', 'Guava', 'Muskmelon', 'Watermelon', 'Orange', 'Sapota']
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateDataWithKey();
  }

  updateDataWithKey() {
    const { arrayList } = this.state;
    const dataWithKey = arrayList.map(data => {
      return {'key': data}
    });
    this.setState({dataWithKey, filterData: dataWithKey});
  }

  changeText(text) {
    this.setState({text});
    const { dataWithKey } = this.state;
    if (text !== '') {
      let filterData = dataWithKey.filter(obj => {
        return obj.key.toLowerCase().indexOf(text.trim().toLowerCase()) > -1;
      });
      if (filterData.length === 0) {
        filterData = [{key: 'No Filter Data'}];
      }
      this.setState({filterData});
    } else {
      this.setState({filterData: dataWithKey});
    }
  }

  onListItemClicked(text) {
    this.setState({
      text,
      textInputFocus: false,
      filterData: [{key: text}]
    });
  }

  renderRow(item) {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.onListItemClicked(item.key)}
        style={styles.listItem}
      >
        <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  handleInputFocus() {
    this.setState({textInputFocus: true});
  }

  handleInputBlur() {
    this.setState({textInputFocus: false});
  }

  render() {
    const { filterData, textInputFocus } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.textInput}
          onFocus={() => this.handleInputFocus()}
          onBlur={() => this.handleInputBlur()}
          placeholder="Search & Select List!"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.changeText(text)}
          value={this.state.text}
        />
        {textInputFocus &&
          <FlatList
            data={filterData}
            renderItem={({item}) => this.renderRow(item)}
          />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 8,
    paddingTop: 12
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 40,
    marginLeft: 5,
  },
  item: {
    padding: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    height: 44,
  },
})
```

Answer (score -1):

you may use [native-base-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/native-base-autocomplete) the api is taken from [react-native-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input). check out [snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@thg303/native-base-autocomplete) of how to use it.